# Bash/Rsync: One-way synchronize files, leave files alone when only metadata has changed

Tags: bash, sync, rsync, metadata

I have some programs that allow exporting to different formats (e.g.
html), but many of them share a problem: Exports are always done "all
together", i.e. things like images or attachments are created new in
the export folder on every export, even if they have not changed since
last exporting. Also, usually they don't take care of removing
deprecated files or may even fail when the directory already contains
files. I've seen similiar problems with the export functionalities of
different programs, currently my use-case is ZIM Desktop Wiki.

I thought I could just export to a temporary directory and then use
rsync to synchronize the exported file to the final export directory,
e.g. Google Drive or Dropbox. Using rsync however, I couldn't find a
way to integrate the changed files into the target directory without
changing the modification times of files that did NOT actually change,
which is likely to confuse either backups of the directory and/or the
cloud synchronization, causing unnecessary upload traffic in one case,
duplicate files on the drive with the incremental backups in the other
and a huge waste of time in both.

Is there some way to make rsync do a check by actual file contents and
leave meta-data alone for files that are the same, or some existing
solution other than rsync?

Answer (score 1):

From the rsync man page:

> -c, --checksum :  skip based on checksum, not mod-time &
>   size

Comment: Doesn't preserve the modtime of unchanged files, so it is still likely to confuse other software.